# Import of apache velocity in gradle downgrades HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, dependencies, apache-velocity

I have a spring boot project with the following code:

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

foo(NativeWebRequest req){
    HttpServletResponse res = req.getNativeResponse(HttpServletResponse.class);
    res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
}
```

And everything worked fine until I added velocity dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity', version: '1.7'
compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity-tools', version: '2.0'
```

Now I get:
In Eclipse: `The method setCharacterEncoding(String) is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse`
And in `gradle bootJar`:

```
.../SomeFile.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
            res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
               ^
  symbol:   method setCharacterEncoding(String)
  location: variable res of type HttpServletResponse
```

So I figure that the version of the library that imports HttpServletResponse is somehow impacted by those dependencies.

my spring boot plugin is: `id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'`

All dependencies in the same project are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity
    compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity', version: '1.7'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity-tools
    compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity-tools', version: '2.0'
}
```

From `gradle dependencies` I can see that velocity sets `javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.3` but without the velocity dependencies `javax.servlet` doesn't appear in gradle dependencies at all, so I don't know what the version was before.

From commenting out I could determine that `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'` provides javax.servlet if velocity is not a dependency. (per `gradle dependencies` Version 2.3.2 in `compileClasspath` and `(n)` in `implementation`)

I also tried `gradle dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency javax.servlet:servlet-api` without velocity, but got `No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration 'compile'`.

I think these questions come very close, but I'm still unsure how to proceed in gradle:
[setCharacterEncoding problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710668/setcharacterencoding-problems)
[Apache Velocity + Servlet 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311990/apache-velocity-servlet-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

replacing
`compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity-tools', version: '2.0'`
with

```
compile('org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'
}
```

worked for me.